# Send default value to form from controller

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a loop in which a create a form for each "Joueur" I have :

```
    foreach ($joueurs as $j) 
    {
        $sUniqueFormName = 'Form' . $j->getId(); 
        $oForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed($sUniqueFormName, PlayedType::class, $played);
        $aForms[$sUniqueFormName] = $oForm;            
    }
```

I want to send to my form this Entity Joueur and set it as the default value.

Form :

```
class PlayedType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('joueur')
            ->add('max')
            ->add('score')
            ->add('points')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Played::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here, the 'joueur' attribute is a choice type and and want to set this value with the 'joueur' I get in the loop as default.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an array as 4th arg with the $j value:

```
foreach ($joueurs as $j) 
{
    $sUniqueFormName = 'Form' . $j->getId(); 
    $oForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed($sUniqueFormName, PlayedType::class, $played, array('joueur' => $j);
    $aForms[$sUniqueFormName] = $oForm;            
}
```

Check the constructor for more info: https://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html

And recover it in PlayedType by $options and set it as data property

```
class PlayedType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->add('joueur', null, array(
                 'data' => $event->getData() ?: options['joueur']
             ))
            ->add('max')
            ->add('score')
            ->add('points')
            ;
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Played::class,
            'joueur' => null
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data _"The `data` option **always** overrides the value taken from the domain data (object) when rendering. This means the object value is also overriden when the form edits an already persisted object, causing it to lose its persisted value when the form is submitted."_

Comment: Doesn't work, I get this error : The option "joueur" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file..... Do I have to set this joueur in configureOptions or something ?

Comment: Symfony version?

Comment: I use Symfony 4.2

Comment: I forgot something. Check my edit in configureOptions function. You must add joueur property there

Comment: @PatrickRey but you know this solution won't work any longer if you are using this `FormType` as an edit form, because the `data` option overwrites the saved data from the object

Comment: Yes I read your comment, I just use it as a new form for the moment, so it's ok. But, if you have a better option I'll take it :)

Comment: In order to avoid the case (override the data) that @Fabian is saying, you must use $event->getData() ?: options['joueur'] instead options['joueur'] only. I edit my answer

Comment: from where do you get this $event variable ?

Comment: When the form is submmited, 'joueur' field will get the data of himself that the user sent.

Comment: @PatrickRey `$options['data']` instead of `$event` will do the same

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it says "Notice: Undefined variable: event" or if I put $options['data'] instead of $event : Attempted to call an undefined method named "getData" of class "App\Entity\Played".

Comment: Check now. I didnt add the listenner for catching the event.

Comment: Nope, no yet :D : Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Form\PlayedType::App\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Form\FormEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent given, called in

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `joueur` directly on the `played` entity like this for example:

```
foreach ($joueurs as $j) {
    $sUniqueFormName = 'Form' . $j->getId();
    $played->setJoueur($j);
    $oForm = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed($sUniqueFormName, PlayedType::class, $played);
    $aForms[$sUniqueFormName] = $oForm;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately :/ In the form, the attribute value of joueur is not set